# my java application doesnt work and i have no clue why

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a simple application that creates a 2D Grid based off of its dimensions and then prints it, but the main method throws an error every time. what am i doing wrong?

```
static void int[][] createGrid(int x, int y) {
    int Grid[][] = new int[x][y];

    for (int a = 0; a < Grid.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < Grid[a].length; a++) {
            //check if there is something that currently needs to go there
            //else 
            Grid[a][b] = 0;
        }
    }
}
public static void printgrid (int[][] Grid) {
    for (int a = 0; a < Grid.length; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < Grid[a].length; b++) {
            System.out.print(Grid[a][b]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printgrid(createGrid(10, 20));

}
```

}

Comment: What is the error?  How about an example of the desired output?

Comment: Add your error/exception to your question (just [edit] it).

Comment: The `main` method doesn't print anything - it doesn't even compile.

Comment: There are 2 compiler errors that I'll leave to the OP as an excercise, but the main problem is likely a typo in the inner loop in `createGrid`, where `a` is incremented instead of `b`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return `Grid` from `createGrid`:

```
return Grid;
```

Also, you can only specify one return type from `createGrid` (remove the `void`):

```
static int[][] createGrid(int x, int y) {
```

You should study the error messages from your compiler: they might look cryptic at first, but they actually tell you the exact problem.